# Javascript function issue not returning the desired value

Tags: javascript

I know this may sound somehow stupid, but I have been having issue with this part on [The common online tutorial website](http://codecademy.com), Please i need your help with function declaration and returning a particular value.
The question is as follows.

> You are a creature of habit. Every week you buy 5 oranges. But orange
>   prices keep changing!
>
> You want to declare a function that calculates the cost of buying 5 oranges.
>       You then want to calculate the cost of the 5 all together.
>       Write a function that does this called orangeCost().
>       It should take a parameter that is the cost of an orange, and multiply it by 5.
>       It should log the result of the multiplication to the console.
>       Call the function where oranges each cost 5 dollars.

Here is my solution but it's not working out.

```
var calOrange = function orangeCost(price, amount) {
    console.log("The price for your five oranges is" + " " + calOrange);
}
calOrange(25 * 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function does not calculate the result. In order to do that, you should only pass the parameters (`(5,5)`) to it and make the multiplication inside.

Second of all, I'm not sure why you try to use `calOrange` inside the function which you are assigning to this very variable?

Finally, you are expected to calculate total cost of five oranges that cost $5 each. You should use two fives as arguments then:

```
function orangeCost(price, amount) {
    console.log("The price for your five oranges is " + price * amount);
}

calOrange(5, 5); // "The price for your five oranges is 25"
```

Comment: Please explain the code in your answer. Code only answers are typically frowned upon on SO